Can a (countably) infinite set be randomized?
I have been thinking for some time about the following question: Can a countably infinite set, such as the natural numbers, be randomized by a suitable shuffling process?
For this purpose it is relevant to define first the fully ordered set: $A(i) = i \space$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$
The next step is to construct a function which is a measure of how much a given (randomized) state deviates from the fully ordered state. I do not think there is a unique "best" choice for such a function. I considered two choices:
$$S = \sum _{i=1} ^\infty \space \frac{1}{i} \space  |\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{A(i)}|$$
$$S = \sum _{i=1} ^\infty \space [\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{A(i)}]^2$$
Both of these work fine, in the sense that they yield zero for the fully ordered set. And they are both maximal for a fully randomized set. Although the latter can not be truely realized, we can establish that since there are far more very large numbers in the set than small numbers, after randomization the very large numbers will occupy all the initial places in the set whereas all the small numbers have been shuffled far away towards infinity. With this in mind the sums can be evaluted. The first yields $\pi^2 /6$ and the second $\pi^2 /3$ . If so desired, we can scale the $S$-function to a value between $0$ and $1$.
We now only have to choose methods for the actual randomization process, which translates into repeatedly shuffling the $A(i)$ such that $S$ increases to its maximal value. Which is a straightforward optimization process. One simple method is to choose a random value of $i$ between $1$ and $\infty$, and similarly a second value j. We can then switch the values of $A(i)$ and $A(i+j)$ if this increases $S$. If not, we do nothing and choose new $i$ and $j$. By repeating this process we do randomize the $A(i)$ set, but obviously we can not achieve full randomization since this would require infinitely many steps.
Is what I described here feasible? Does it make mathematical sense?

This approach works with finite sets. But I'm not sure I would call any reordering of, say,  ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}$ a "randomization."

As you shuffle, doesn't the limit in the second expression of $S$ also equal $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{A(i)}]^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

It depends on what you mean by "randomized".
You can develop a method that potentially gives any of the permutations of the positive integers. While requiring a countably infinite number of steps to give all the terms, it can takes a finite number of steps to generate a finite number of initial terms.  For example, use any distribution you like supported on the positive integers to choose the first term, then do the same to chose the second term from those that remain (possibly with a different distribution supported on the positive integers), and then the third term from those unselected so far, and so on. In this case, though you can choose your selection method so each particular  potential full permutation will have probability $0$ in a similar sense to a uniform distribution on the real numbers in $[0,1]$, different permutations will not be equally likely, and the first step will determine the distribution of the initial term of the permutation.
You cannot develop a method which makes each possible permutation equally likely, or which has $S$ achieving the bounds for your suggested measures of randomness. You say "after randomization the very large numbers will occupy all the initial places in the set whereas all the small numbers have been shuffled far away towards infinity" but there are no numbers which really count as a "very large number" here, since for any number there are many more which are extremely even bigger. One way of seeing the difficulty is to consider the probability that the first term in the permutation is some given $k$: if this probability is positive for any $k$, then that $k$ is more likely than an infinite number of other possible values; if the probability is $0$ for all $k$, then the probability there is a first term at  all is $0$ (the countable sum of probabilities of disjoint events) when it should be $1$; if it is unmeasurable for any $k$ then you have left the domain of probability theory.
